# Размер hover блока

Tags: html, css

Какая задача, как сделать чтобы размер вылетающего блока dropdown-content был по всей ширине экрана и не превышал 1358px т.е если это экран ноута допустим 1366px в ширину то размер блока dropdown-content был 1358 и находися по центру экрана, если это монитор в 1280px то блок dropdown-content был по всей ширине экрана но и не превышал 1358px

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
{
    .dropdown
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content
    {
        z-index: 1;
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #000;


        padding: 46px 24px 40px;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .__open
    {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #4a4a4a;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
    {
        display:block;
    }
}
</style>

<header>
    <a class="LOGO" href="#">LOGO</a>
    <nav>
            <div style="">
                    <a class="" href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
                    <a class="" href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
                    <a class="" href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="__open" href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="" href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
                    <a class="" href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
            </div>
    </nav>
<hedaer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Честно говоря, очень непонятно что Вам нужно, и кривоватая html разметка. В случаи Вашей разметки `class="dropdown"` вообще можно вынести за блок с `а` ссылками.

Если правильно понял, то вы хотите сделать вот так вот (нужно добавить к существующим стилям):

```
.dropdown-content {
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1358px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```